# upgrade WebLogic from 10.3.2 to 12.1.1

Tags: weblogic-10.x, weblogic12c

1.Is it possible to upgrade the WebLogic application server version
   from 10.3.2 to 12.1.1 with some utility (like an inplace upgrade)?
   How much time it will take?

1. Is it possible to install new version prior to go-live with the same port number so that we can reduce the downtime requirement? 
   If same port number is not possible during installation, how easy to
   change the port numbers during the go-live?

Answer (score 2):

You can upgrade weblogic 10.3.2 to 12c...

Before upgrading you need to check the compatibility..

Please check the below link for more details...

http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLUPG/compat.htm

you can use the different port number while installing...But later you can change the port numbers which are same as 10.3.2

Once the application is good with other port numbers then you can change those ports as per your requirement on go live day...so you need to shutdown/stop the 10.3.2 instance and need to start the 12c instace...